# Getting Value cannot be null. Parameter name: items, MVC4 selectList error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i recently had the dropdownlist working and everything was fine but for some reason it is now throwing value cannot be null exception. I have swapped variable names around and things trying to resolve the error but has had no effect. Could you please take a look at my code and point me in the right direction. I am a beginner with MVC4 and have been working on this problem for hours now, so any help would be appreciated. I have only posted relevant code thanks in advance.

EDIT: it is throwing the error at start of line @Html.DropDownListFor(....) in the view

Model:

```
public partial class SiteBookingsTable
{        
    public string departureAirport { get; set; }
    public string arrivalAirport { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Flying From")]
    public string chooseDepartureAirport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Flying To")]
    public string chooseArrivalAirport { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Project56.Models.SiteBookingsTable
@{
List<Project56.Models.SiteBookingsTable> selectDepFlight = ViewBag.depList;
}

<tr>
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.chooseDepartureAirport)<br /> 
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.chooseDepartureAirport, new SelectList(selectDepFlight,"departureAirport","departureAirport"))</td>                    
</tr>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<SiteBookingsTable> selectDepFlight = new List<SiteBookingsTable>();

        selectDepFlight.Add(new SiteBookingsTable() { listID = 0, departureAirport = "-Select-" });
        selectDepFlight.Add(new SiteBookingsTable() { listID = 1, departureAirport = "London (LTN)" });
        selectDepFlight.Add(new SiteBookingsTable() { listID = 2, departureAirport = "Manchester (MAN)" });

        ViewBag.depList = selectDepFlight;


        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SiteBookingsTable aBooking)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
        {
            newBooking.SiteBookingsTables.Add(aBooking);
            newBooking.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(aBooking);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your View you are using `SelectList(selectDepFlight,`

but you are sending a ViewBag variable `ViewBag.depList = selectDepFlight;`

you want `SelectList(ViewBag.depList,`

although honestly it should probably be in the Model, not the ViewBag

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly the SelectList type must be enumerable.  --[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

** Edit, its probably best to return the value as an enumerable from the controller side instead of in the View itself.  Also consider utilizing ViewModels and not the Model itself.

```
List<Project56.Models.SiteBookingsTable> selectDepFlight = ViewBag.depList;

//Add the following line(s) to cast your list to an enumerable.

IEnumerable<Project56.Models.SiteBookingsTable> enumSelectDepFlight = selectDepFlight.AsEnumerable<Project56.Models.SiteBookingsTable>

//Alter the following code 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.chooseDepartureAirport, new SelectList(selectDepFlight,"departureAirport","departureAirport"))

//to match the enumerable above

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.chooseDepartureAirport, new SelectList(enumSelectDepFlight,"departureAirport","departureAirport"))
```